# How to auto generate particular value in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I auto generate particular values in a table's column? I want to auto generate values in column like `"WD-2010-0001","WD-2010-0002", "WD-2010-0003"`and so on. Can anyone help ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where do these values come from? Are these values combinations of things that are in other columns in the table?

Comment: what are the values `WD` and `2015,2010` ??

Comment: It's usually best to keep the separate parts (that vary, but in different ways) in separate column(s), and then have a computed column (or view) that constructs the formatted value. If that's suitable, can you tell us what the rules are for how things vary? Is `WD-` always fixed to those characters?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I'd store different parts separately then format them using a computed column. This could be as simple as:

```
create table T (
    _ID int IDENTITY(20100001,1) not null,
    ID as 'WD-' + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(10),_ID),4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),_ID),5,10),
    ColumnA int not null
)
go
insert into T(ColumnA) values (10)
go
select ID,ColumnA from T
```

Which produces:

```
ID                 ColumnA
------------------ -----------
WD-2010-0001       10
```

And the next insert would be `WD-2010-0002`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

use an expression in a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.test2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.test2
CREATE TABLE dbo.test2
 (
  Id int IDENTITY,
  colLikeWd varchar(2) DEFAULT 'WD',
  colLikeYear varchar(4) DEFAULT '2010',
  colLikeAuto AS colLikeWd + '-' + colLikeYear + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(Id AS varchar(4)), 4),
  colAnother varchar(100)
  )
GO 

INSERT dbo.test2(colAnother)
VALUES('AnotherColumn')
GO 5  

SELECT *
FROM dbo.test2
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/256ca/2)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to say what you really want to do, but it could be something like

```
select
    'WD-20' + 
    right('00' + cast(cast(rand() * 15 as int) + 1 as nvarchar(2)), 2) + '-' +
    '000' + cast(cast(rand() * 9 as int) + 1 as nvarchar(1))
```

Comment: Scenario is that every time i insert new record in table then it generate "WD-2010-0001","WD-2010-0002". i want to use these auto generate values as id like in regular scenario "id" column generate value 1,2,3 and so on....

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP means is not how to generate that particular values, but how to fill the columns automatically. I think using triggers is the right way to go. Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Add_WD] on dbo.MyTable AFTER INSERT AS
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET WD = '' -- you can put your value generation logic here.
FROM Inserted i
WHERE dbo.MyTable.PrimaryId = i.PrimaryId
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
DECLARE @String varchar(20)='WD-2010-0001'

SELECT 'WD-2010-'+
        REPLICATE('0', 4 - LEN(REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@String),
                  CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@String)) -1)) AS INT)+1 )))+ 
       CAST(CAST(REVERSE(left(REVERSE(@String), CHARINDEX('-', 
               REVERSE(@String)) -1)) AS INT)+1 AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Replace `@String`  with your `column name`